# Android: how to manage Google API SHA1 for development vs production?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

To access Google Apis from android, I need to create a client Id for my application.  This client ID requires generating a Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) from the keystore used to sign the app.  The tutorial in the below link instructs to generate this SHA1 using eclipse's debug keystore, which is the one I use for development.

However, when I sign the production version of my app I will do so with another keystore -- do I need to create a separate client ID for the second keystore?

Also, I reference the client id in my application's manifest (to integrate with the drive app), do I need to change this id when I build my app for release?

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a separate client ID for the second keystore. SHA1 values are related to the key itself; they're a "signature" for the key.

Put the release client ID in the manifest for your released app.

THe tutorial shows you how to get started quickly with Google Drive using Android. It's not meant for implementing a released app. Unfortunately, the instructions for released apps seem to be broken.